# Cannot read all sheets of the excel file using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, list

This program works well for reading 1st sheet of the excel file, while I am trying to read all the sheets of the excel file I cannot read all the sheets.

```
python
```

while I add `sheet_name = None` in the reading excel line
I am getting error like this I can not find out what is the error and how to rectify the error.

```
(scrap-3-HFZx_P-py3.9) PS F:\mohan> & C:/Users/hp/AppData/Local/pypoetry/Cache/virtualenvs/scrap-3-HFZx_P-py3.9/Scripts/python.exe f:/mohan/main.py
ENTER THE LIST HERE : userid,city,state
enter the full path to the file : F:\\mis\\KB.xlsx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\mohan\main.py", line 16, in <module>     
    print(obj.extract(file_name))
  File "f:\mohan\main.py", line 9, in extract       
    return raw_excel[conf].to_dict(orient='records')
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: If use one sheetname, it means instead `userid,city,state` only `userid` solution working?

Comment: `raw_excel[conf].to_dict(orient='records')` this line is probably wrong ... you mean `raw_excel[self.config].to_dict(orient='records')` ?

Comment: what is expected ouput if pass multiple `sheetname`s ? dictionary of each sheetname?

Comment: @jezrael  my expected output is list of dictionaries that containing all sheets specified column values

Comment: @asifzuba if change conf to config im getting the same error

 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\mohan\main.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(obj.extract(file_name))
  File "f:\mohan\main.py", line 9, in extract
    return raw_excel[self.config].to_dict(orient='records')
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Yes, that won't solve your error, but it is definitely wrong... you are getting away here because you have `conf` defined outside your class. Please see the answers for more clarity on your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
#output is nested lists of list of dictionaries
def extract(self, file_name):
    raw_excel=pd.read_excel(file_name,sheet_name=None)
    return [v[v.columns.intersection(conf)].to_dict(orient='records')
                  for k, v in raw_excel.items()]
```

**Explanation**:

If use `sheet_name=None` output is dictionary of DataFrames, here `raw_excel`.

If need loop by dict here is used list comprehension with method `items`, so `v` is `value`s and `k` for `key`s.

For filter only columns from DataFrame if exist in `conf` is used [`Index.intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html).

Last is used `to_dict`, so get for each DataFrame list of dictionaries. Final output, in another words `return` get lists of list of dictionaries.

If need flatten ouput is possible use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/952952/2901002):

```
flat_list = [item for sublist in t for item in sublist]
```

So code is changed:

```
#output is flatten list of dictionaries
def extract(self, file_name):
    raw_excel=pd.read_excel(file_name,sheet_name=None)
    return [x for k, v in raw_excel.items() 
               for x in v[v.columns.intersection(conf)].to_dict(orient='records')]
```

Answer (score 0):

- This is a bit quirky, but when you do `sheet_name=None`, the returned type is not a pandas `DataFrame` but a `dict`. I personally don't like when return type changes with different arguments but it is what it is
- However, this solves the mystery of the type error. Because you are now getting a dict back, and so when you subset with a list ...it can't do that operation and will give you a Unhashable Type error.
- I would suggest that you have a conditional which checks for type and then does some extra processing.
- Let me know if you need an elaborate example for type checking.

Comment: @MohanrajM - list comprehension not working?

Comment: That's not working that change shows key error..
'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\mohan\main.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(obj.extract(file_name))
  File "f:\mohan\main.py", line 9, in extract
    return [raw_excel[x].to_dict(orient='records') for x in conf]      
  File "f:\mohan\main.py", line 9, in <listcomp>
    return [raw_excel[x].to_dict(orient='records') for x in conf]      
KeyError: 'col_RequestID'
'